# DocuSign API call is Failing with Error, DocuSign returned the following error code: 200

Tags: docusignapi, appian

I am trying to integrate Appian with DocuSign. I have been able to create & authenticate connected system successfully. But when I am trying to call API **Send Document For eSignature**, I am getting this error not sure why. Please help me with it.

[image]

Comment: Can you click the response tab and tell us the data presented there?

Comment: @bendowlingtech Response tab has,  Json Response :"Failed to convert the response to json"

Comment: Probably will need more details to troubleshoot this. Please create a support case here: https://support.docusign.com/en/contactSupport

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue resolved, The issue was with "Instance URL" which was not configured correctly in connected system file.